# One Page Checkout freezes at step 1 and doesn't progress ahead

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am on Magento 1.9.3 and am facing issue one page checkout. It is not showing any of the steps to be used for checkout.

[image: Here is the screenshot of checkoutpage]

While checking console, I am getting following errors:

Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).childElements is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setAttribute is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: this.toggleElements.toggleSingle is not a function

I have installed some of the extensions and it seems to be conflict issue but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does one of your extensions or you yourself add jQuery to the theme? Magento 1.x uses prototype.js in many places which also uses $ like jQuery. If you have both those conflict and this might result in this behaviour. Make sure that you use jQuery in no conflict mode or consider attaching jQuery to something else than $.